# angular - route redirection doesent works until i reload the page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I want to redirect from one page to another and I use this code:

```
this.navCtrl.navigateRoot(this.routeService.generateUrl(APP_PATHS.checkOut.modules.address));
```

So it gives me the correct URL:

```
www.mysebsite.com/checkout/address
```

but it doesn't show me the content of that page until I click refresh or reload the page, any help? how it can show the page content without my manual refreshing of the page?

```
navCtrl = NavController  

  import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';


routeService = RouteService

import { RouteService } from '@app/core/services/route.service';
```

this.routeService.generateUrl givig bak URL that i want

Comment: Check your console if you have any error/warning messages, you should include it...

Comment: no error or warnings

Comment: What is `navCtrl`? And what is `this.routeService.generateUrl` giving back?

Comment: @DaniloKörber i update description

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this line of code:

```
window.location.href  = this.routeService.generateUrl(APP_PATHS.checkOut.modules.address);
```